# Cannot Log On - Not Enough Resources

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit

I only have one account on this computer (password protected) and it is an administrator. Whenever I try to log on it gives me an error message that it is impossible to log on due to a lack of resources.

I tried going on safe mode (it logs on automatically) and creating a new user account but I get no reaction from Windows when I click on "Manage another account". Windows just does nothing when I try to click on it.

Why is it not letting me log in?

Comment: "lack of resources" isn't the same thing as lack of privileges or permissions, which you seem to be confusing it with. Sounds like you don't have enough RAM or something, although booting into safe mode should have helped that...

Comment: @martineau Right, I also checked the RAM in safe mode and it was around 740 MO out of 3GB ... CPU is down at 1-20%. I also had all the priviledges in normal Windows. I can only log on if I use safe-mode and that's where I click on "Manage another account" but get no results.

Comment: That's not much, especially if you were in safe mode. Try it again and this time start the Task Manager and see if you can see what process is consuming so much of your memory.

Comment: Try browsing to http://update.microsoft.com in Internet Explorer and get the latest updates for your OS.

Comment: The only process higher than 10k is "MsMpEng.exe" (18,968k, which seems to be Windows Defender). I tried starting Windows Updates but the window never appears.

Comment: Well. if you've got Windows Defender or Microsoft Security Essentials installed, do a full scan of your hard disk(s) and see if it finds anything.

Comment: Is this a domain workstation?  I have seen a similar issue when a user changes their password too frequently on their own.  Have a domain admin force a password change and see if that clears the issue.

Comment: @NewProgrammerJames This is a home workgroup station. Actually it is my girlfriend's laptop and she never changes her password. It just randomly started doing this.

Answer (score 2):

Login in safe mode with prompt. From there run `sfc /scannow` .

If after this ([sfc](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/1538-sfc-scannow-command-system-file-checker.html)) the problem isn't fixed, try creating a new account and migrate your data.

note: as stated before, the problem might reside in your ram starting to give out problems. i would check with [memtestx86](http://www.memtest86.com/). there might as well be a process consuming your RAM. check that possibility running `taskmgr` from the same prompt.

Comment: I just want to mention that sfc can be a huge rabbit hole when it fails to repair things -- sfcfix might help, but otherwise you'll need help, and in the end if it can't repair a few .png files from Microsoft Edge, I don't think it's important to fix.

Answer (score 1):

The message you've been given is probably clue enough to what the problem is.  I've seen similar stuff with virus-ridden pc's.  I'd check your task manager if you can and see what the resource usage is like.  If you could get some more sticks of memory together that'd help.  Even a single stick of 2gb would be fine.

If it works with new/extra memory, then you know what the problem is.